# Getting error when trying to return the last item added to a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, linq, gridview

I am trying to get the last item inserted into a table however I am getting the error: Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource. Is there another way? I just want the id returned.
Here is my code.

```
 using (ProjectEntities myEntities = new ProjectEntities())
        {
            var lastin = (from B in myEntities.Books
                          orderby B.Id descending
                          select Booking.Id).First();
            GridView1.DataSource = lastin;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: You're selecting a single element, not a list, and putting it somewhere that requires a list, and it is giving you an error that says it's not getting a list. If you don't want a list, why are you trying to populate a grid view?

Comment: I am unsure of what else to use. I thought grid would be the easy thing to do. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I got it I made it a label and did label.text = lastin.tostring()